# Running PySide6 and GPIO on Raspberry PI 4

Tags: user-interface, raspberry-pi, pyside, qt-quick, pyside6

Recently I have bought a brand new Raspberry Pi 4B with 8Gb RAM and installed Ubuntu Desktop 21.04 there.

My goal is to create a GUI on a touchscreen which controls GPIO pins (some hardware devices).

Since controlling GPIO is done by Python I would like to use is to write GUI as well. I saw a couple of tutorials and decided to use PySide6 + Qt Quick. This kind of program runs fine on my personal laptop but when trying to download required dependencies on Raspberry, like:

`python3.9 -m pip install PySide6`

I got the following error:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement PySide6 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for PySide6
```

I suppose the issue might be caused by the cross compiling.

Do you know if there is any chance of running PySide6 and QtQuick on a Raspberry Pi 4B?

**UPDATE**:

Tested on a Raspberry Pi 4B with Manjaro ARM KDE Plasma 21.07 64 bit OS

Run the following commands:

```
* Update the package database and update all packages on the OS:
  sudo pacman -Syu

* Install PySide6:
  sudo pacman -Syu pyside6

* Install Qt6:
  sudo pacman -Syu qt6

* Install pip3:
  sudo pacman -Syu python-pip

* Install gpizero using pip3:
  sudo pip3 install gpiozero

* Install rpi.gpio:
  sudo env CFLAGS="-fcommon" pip install rpi.gpio

* Support access to gpio:
  sudo groupadd gpio
  sudo usermod -a -G gpio user
  sudo su
  cat << EOF > /etc/udev/rules.d/90-gpio.rules
  KERNEL=="gpiomem", OWNER="root", GROUP="gpio"
  EOF
  exit
```

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to build pyside6 for raspbian bullseye but after several attempts of 8-10 hour builds and running into weird errors I've decided to try your method and switch to manjaro. I can confirm that your method to install PySide6 works. Next goal is to play with this flavour of linux and get comfortable with the envoinrment.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).